# Solr : Commitwithin not working with custom UpdateRequestProcessorFactory

Tags: solr

I have written a custom handler. but the thing is commitWithin is not working and commit="true" is working. Here is my config file.

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="mytestupdatehandler"  default="true">
   <processor class="com.solr.handler.interceptor"></processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>

<requestHandler name="/MypdateHandler" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" >
   <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="update.chain">mytestupdatehandler</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <!-- See below for information on defining 
     updateRequestProcessorChains that can be used by name 
     on each Update Request
     -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="maxThreads">50</str>     
        <str name="handlerType">asyncXML</str>
        <str name="sharedError">false</str>             
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Also i checked my log files and it shows

Mar 3, 2014 1:09:56 PM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/LMUpdateHandler params={wt=json} {add=[checkcommitwithtrue]} 0 124
Mar 3, 2014 1:09:57 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
INFO: start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=true,prepareCommit=false}
Mar 3, 2014 1:09:57 PM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher 
INFO: Opening Searcher@225bcd91 main
Mar 3, 2014 1:09:57 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
INFO: end_commit_flush

Comment: Also when i give commit=true in the query it works. the data is not lost. but when i give commitWithin in add the query it is not getting savedd